# Should we close questions asking for "authentic" translations as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

*[Authentic text of Surya Siddhanta English Translation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24362/authentic-text-of-surya-siddhanta-english-translation)* lists several English translations and then asks which among them is "authentic"?

Now who is supposed to qualify any particular translation as "authentic"? The user posting the answer? And how do we determine if the user's opinion is valid?

I think we should automatically close all questions asking for "authentic" anything as opinion-based unless users themselves define what they mean by *authentic* and the definition is not subjective.

Some users here prefer Indian translations of Hindu scripture over Western translations. In that case, they can ask a question like this which can be answered objectively:

> [Translation of Rig Veda by an Indian author](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12151/translation-of-rig-veda-by-an-indian-author)

Comment: IMO, we can have such discussions on meta but not on the main site. I would have not suggested meta too but here there isn't much activity. So, anything such discussions which could increase activity should be welcome at this stage.

Comment: Yes, the question has been closed now.